# What is the simple Linux utility that is like cat but works via TCP (to be used for port knocking)?

Tags: linux, firewall, tcp

For port knocking over at my old job, one of the SAs use to perform something like the following:

```
 echo 'blah' > tcpcat -a 192.168.3.1 -p 2222 && ssh beamin@192.168.3.1
```

I cannot remember the command that I am referring to as `tcpcat`. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ncat` may be the tool you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like that is it! Thanks sir. Have to wait 12 minutes to award you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may be called netcat, Lowercase nc is what the command actually is.